# Why is this assigned HTML id returning 0 when calling it? React/SPFX

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, spfx

I'm trying to get the Id of a clicked item in a List. This list is being retrieved from a SharePoint list.
Here's the JSX:

```
<List items={this.state.filtPanelMeetFiles.map(file => <div>{file.FileLeafRef}</div>)} onRenderCell={this._onRenderCellFiles} />

private _onRenderCellFiles = (item) => {
    return(
      <div>
        <tr data-is-scrollable>
          <td style={{ width: '150px' }} >{item}</td>
          <td style={{ width: '150px' }} >{item.Id}</td>
          <td style={{ width: '15px' }}>
            <div className={styles.editIcon}><Icon iconName="Delete" id={item.Id} onClick={this._deleteFile} />
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The above `id={item.Id}` always brings back 0 whatever item is clicked.

I retrieve the list and display it in an identical way on some other code and that successfully retrieves the Id.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy work around will be to use the key method and add the index to the list,
You can try like this (Using the MAP function and passing it as KEY in the list)

```
export default function App() {
const List = ['Hello', 'World']
const clickHandler = (i)=>{
  console.log(i)
}
return (
<div className="App">
  {List.map((element, index)=>(
    <li key = {index} onClick = {(event)=> {event.preventDefault; clickHandler(index)}}>{element}</li>
  ))}
</div>
  );
}
```

This will work out :)

check this code for a example (also open the console before trying it out)

[Check the Code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-dan-te2x4?file=/src/App.js)

```html
<iframe src="https://codesandbox.io/embed/fervent-dan-te2x4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark"
     style="width:100%; height:500px; border:0; border-radius: 4px; overflow:hidden;"
     title="fervent-dan-te2x4"
     allow="accelerometer; ambient-light-sensor; camera; encrypted-media; geolocation; gyroscope; hid; microphone; midi; payment; usb; vr; xr-spatial-tracking"
     sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts"
   ></iframe>
```

Comment: Could you provide an example that is closer to what I provide?

Comment: @Tom I have shown the idea briefly, as you retrive the list, store them in a variable and use the map function and pass the index, so that it'll be fine, kindly look at this sandbox for a clearcut example

Comment: Would I pass the index in the <List items or in the _onRenderCellFiles?

Comment: I would request you to save the retirved list to a variable, like you can get that list store it in a variable and access it more effectively, and it will be more cleaner

Comment: In the _onRenderCellFiles function or within the <List items?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224479/discussion-between-saran-surya-and-tom).